# jQuery load txt file

Tags: jquery, refresh

I use this script to refresh the data on div #puu. If .load() contains existing .php file everything works just fine. But if I use existing .txt file in .load() nothing happens, why is this?

```
<script>
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
     $('#puu').fadeOut("slow").load('152 and 153.txt').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: did you try url_encoding the file name? The spaces are not good for `load` since it has parser for space which is used to get document fragments. Inspect request in browser console network tab for more troubleshooting info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the spaces in the file name to use `%20` for the space. Also your fadeIn is firing before load returns the data.

```
$('#puu').fadeOut("slow")
         .load('152%20and%20153.txt', function() { 
             $(this).fadeIn("slow"); 
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to that filename its taken as null file name check with your filename 
     $('#puu').load('153.txt').fadeIn("slow");